# Not saving user to database immediately

Tags: python, django

I am having an issue where after a user signs up, they are redirected to a dashboard view that has `@login_required`; however, they cannot access it because the user gets saved to my database after 30 seconds for some reason, not instantly. I am wondering how I can sign up a user, and instantly save them so that they pass the `@login_required` field and can be properly redirected to the dashboard.

Signup view

```
def teacher_sign_up(request):
    form = TeacherSignUpForm(request.POST)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TeacherSignUpForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            return redirect('/teacher/dashboard')

        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Make sure all your information is valid')

    else:
        form = TeacherSignUpForm()


    context = {'form' : form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/teacher_sign_up.html', context)
```

Dashboard view

```
@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'teacher/dashboard.html')
```

forms.py

```
    class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
        email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Email', 'id' : 'email', 'required' : 'True'}))
        first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'First name', 'id' : 'first-name', 'required' : 'True'}))
        last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Last name', 'id' : 'last-name', 'required' : 'True'}))
        password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Password', 'id' : 'password', 'required' : 'True'}))
        password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Confirm password', 'id' : 'password2', 'required' : 'True'}))
        class Meta:
            model = User
            # what fields from that model you want
            fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', 'password2')

        def clean_email(self):
            email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
            qs = User.objects.filter(email=email)
            if qs.exists():
                raise forms.ValidationError("Email is taken")
            return email

        def clean_password2(self):
            # Check that the two password entries match
            password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
            password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
            if password and password2 and password != password2:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
            return password2

        def save(self, commit=True):
            # Save the provided password in hashed format
            user = super(RegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)
            user.first_name = self.cleaned_data["first_name"]
            user.last_name = self.cleaned_data["last_name"]
            user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password"])
            #user.active = False send confirmation email
            if commit:
                user.save()
            return user

class TeacherSignUpForm(RegisterForm):
    avatar = forms.ImageField()
    country = CountryField().formfield(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'required' : 'true'}))
    instrument1 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=instrument_list, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))
    instrument2 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=instrument_list, required=False, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))
    instrument3 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=instrument_list, required=False, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))
    instrument4 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=instrument_list, required=False, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))
    instrument5 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=instrument_list, required=False, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))
    level1 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=level_list, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))
    level2 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=level_list, required=False, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))
    level3 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=level_list, required=False, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))
    level4 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=level_list, required=False, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))
    level5 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=level_list, required=False, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))
    language1 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=language_list, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))
    language2 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=language_list, required=False, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))
    language3 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=language_list, required=False, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))
    resume = forms.FileField()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(TeacherSignUpForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.avatar = self.cleaned_data['avatar']
        user.instrument1 = self.cleaned_data['instrument1']
        user.instrument2 = self.cleaned_data['instrument2']
        user.instrument3 = self.cleaned_data['instrument3']
        user.instrument4 = self.cleaned_data['instrument4']
        user.instrument5 = self.cleaned_data['instrument5']
        user.level1 = self.cleaned_data['level1']
        user.level2 = self.cleaned_data['level2']
        user.level3 = self.cleaned_data['level3']
        user.level4 = self.cleaned_data['level4']
        user.level5 = self.cleaned_data['level5']
        user.language1 = self.cleaned_data['language2']
        user.language2 = self.cleaned_data['language2']
        user.language3 = self.cleaned_data['language3']
        user.resume = self.cleaned_data['resume']

        user.teacher = True
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Comment: Which database system are you using?

Comment: @Jeppe I am using sqlite3

Comment: can you provide you TeacherSignUpForm?

Comment: Can you show us the code of `form.save()` and how you access the database?

Comment: Also why you assignming form.save() to user if you are not using it anywhere.

Comment: @Jeppe updated code

Comment: You know you can simply use "UserCreationForm"  from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm and inherit it directly into your TeacherSignUpForm?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your exact database setup, I suspect that the redirect is not working because the new user is not logged in and therefore the `@login_required` decorator redirects the user to the login page instead.

To sign up a user, instantly save them and redirect to the dashboard you need to [login](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in) the new user first:

```py
if form.is_valid():
    user = form.save()
    login(request, user)
    return redirect('/teacher/dashboard')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add more to Passuf answer by doing proper authenication

```
user = form.save()
username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
login(request, user)
return redirect('/teacher/dashboard')
```

you can get authenticate and login from

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login
```

also if your db is not refreshing you can use

```
user.refresh_from_db() #after the user is saved
```